# Passing keyword arguments from URL to Flask api

Tags: python, url, flask-restful, keyword-argument

I stripped my snippets as far as I could.
I want to use arbitrary number of passed keywords and values in my flask application from URL.
For example: http://localhost:5000/duck?order=90 I would like to use order=90 as an item in a dictionary {"order" = 90} or setting its value to a variable.

**The app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from myresource import Quack


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    register_resources(app)

    return app

def register_resources(app):
    api = Api(app)    
    api.add_resource(Quack, '/duck') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

**myresource.py:**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from http import HTTPStatus
from webargs import fields
from webargs.flaskparser import use_kwargs

class Quack(Resource):
    
    @use_kwargs({"order" : fields.Int(missing=20)}
    def get(self, order):          
        return order, HTTPStatus.OK
```

surprisingly, if I test this app, it returns with 20 in any case, consequently, arguments are not passed. Where is my bug?

or, does Anyone know a WORKING example?

Thanks!

I have tried this: https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intermediate-usage.html?highlight=kwargs , but it simply does not work and exits at resource_class_kwargs.

I also tried out some different approach from this community, but none of them worked as expected.

The approach above came from here: https://github.com/TrainingByPackt/Python-API-Development-Fundamentals/blob/master/Lesson08/Exercise54/resources/recipe.py

Answer (score 0):

finally, after a day:

it is working to some extent.
myresource.py:

> ```py
> from flask import request
>
> from flask_restful import Resource from http import HTTPStatus
>
> class Quack(Resource):
>
>     def get(self):   
>         order = request.args.get("order")
>         return order, HTTPStatus.OK
> ```